# ¿Ejemplo simple de volley en android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

Alguien tiene un ejemplo simple de una app usando volley en android studio? he googleado bastante pero todos los tutoriales que he probado tiran error, nullpointerexception, etc, solo quiero que devuelva un string de algun archivo en un servidor o una lista para entender mejor como funciona, espero su consejo, gracias.

Comment: Sería muy bueno que añadieras el código con el que has probado a implementarlo. De esta manera, la comunidad de SOes te podría ayudar en tu caso concreto y tu verías que fallos has cometido para no volverlos a cometer.

Comment: aquí hay un ejemplo : http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/02/android-volley-peticiones-http/